# Is it possible to set Referer header for XHR in HTML Application?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, hta, http-referer

I was making a simple desktop "informer" which supposed to read the JSON data from several webservices, do some basic transforms and present the result.
However, I got stuck when found out what one of my webservices is very picky at certain request headers. As I narrowed down webservice really wants certain combination of `X-Requested-With` and `Referer` headers and returns `Bad Request` otherwise. So here goes the trouble: [specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name) forbids any modification to `Referer` (and IE follows the spec this time!) even despite the fact what my execution environment is supposedly trusted and privileged [HTML Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471(VS.85).aspx).

Is there any workaround? Please advise.

---

FWIW, I'm using the following quirk to make regular XHR work in HTA context:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
```

Comment: Surprisingly, even Firefox console appears to have this restriction lifted...